# Wordpress custom widget not registering

Tags: php, wordpress, web, widget

I am trying to develope a simple wordpress widget and have failed miserably so far.
My own widget would not show up in the admin panel at all so i decided to try the sample widget code supplied in the wordpress codex @ http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API

The same problem persists and i can't seem to find a solution anywhere online.

Exact code i tried: https://gist.github.com/Jeger/5382772

The file is stored in wp-content/plugins/Foo_Widget.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a very simple answer to this question not mentioned in the codex and something that will probably be obvious to someone used to developing for wordpress, but i will leave it here to let others having the same problem find.

On the top of the file there should be something similar to this:

```
/*
Plugin Name: Foo Widget
Description: Foo widget
Version: 1.0
Author: name
License: GPL2
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure if you have activated you widget plugin under plugin section.